# Simple online file-collecting platform

Tags: web-apps, hosted, uploader

I am teaching, and looking for a way to collect coding homework problems from my students. I think of a website, in which

- I can create an account
- anyone with the link can upload files to the account
- only I can view the uploads
- I can batch download all uploads after that.

It should be as simple as possible, focused on this task; no one should have to install anything for this. The uploads would not be large either, in total <100 MB.

Comment: you can use github if your  collect

Comment: @GilbertoQuinteroA: Github does not satisfy the requirement "*only I can view the uploads*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Forms can be set up very easily to do this.

1. Create a form
2. Add a "File upload" question
3. Set the file size limit
4. Get the link and send it to your students

Drawback: It requires them to have a Google account and log in with it.

[image: Google Forms file upload]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might find it worth taking a look at [NBGrader](https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which, rather than a hosting platform that allows students to upload assignments it is a tool that allows you to:

- Set assignments,
- Collect them
- Mark them (including automatically marking some elements, possibly by automatically executing any code with some test data).

While it doesn't solve your hosting problem it may well be worth expanding your search for suitable hosting to allow its use.